# How to get users id form voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How can I get the ID of the users on the voice channel?

More specific
Can I check the number of people and their id's on the voice channel that also has the bot?

Answer (score 1):

The [`VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel) class has a property called [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) (Type: [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)), which contains all members in a [`VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel).

As an example, you can use [`Collection#map`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) to map each member by ID.

```js
<VoiceChannel>.members.map(member => member.id);
// --> ["1234567890123456", "1234567890123456", "1234567890123456"] etc (Array)
```

Since [`VoiceChannel#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), you can use `size` to get how many items are in the aforementioned [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection).

```js
<VoiceChannel>.members.size;
// --> 25 (Integer)
```